# Маленький жучок в коде

Tags: c++

Суть программы в том, что сначала вводится пароль, потом имя, и если что-то из этого не такое как надо, мы выходим; иначе программа спрашивает "Какую задачу мне исполнить?", и в зависимости от ответа запускает калькулятор или таймер. Иначе выводит что нету у него такого и выходит.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int PasswordArmor() {
    long int a, password, my;
    cin >> a;
    password = rand() % a;
    while (my != password) {
        printf("Enter your password: ");
        cin>> my;
        if (my == password) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid password!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int NameArmor() {
    string names[4] = {
        "Leha Khorsun", "Dima Khorsun",
        "Vlad Khorsun", "Olga Fomkina"
    };
    string name;
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    getline(cin, name);
    for (auto a : names) {
        if (name == a) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int Armor() {
    if (PasswordArmor() == 0 && NameArmor() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void Calculator() {
    double a, b, c;
    char op;
    printf("Calculator\n");
    scanf("%lf %c %lf", &a, &op, &b);
    switch(op) {
        case '+':
            c = a + b;
            break;
        case '-':
            c = a - b;
            break;
        case '*':
            c = a * b;
            break;
        case '/':
            c = a / b;
            break;
        case '^':
            c = pow(a, b);
            break;
        case '%':
            c = fmod(a, b);
            break;
        default:
            printf("There isn't such operator in my list! Sorry!");
    }
    cout << a << " " << op << " " << b << " = " << c << endl;
}

void Timer() {
    long long int time;
    bool ready = false;
    printf("Enter time you need to wait: ");
    scanf("%lli", &time);
    while (ready != true) {
        usleep(999999);
        time -= 1;
        printf("%lli \n", time);
        if (time <= 0) {
            ready = true;
        }
    }
    printf("Ready!\n");
    return;
}

int main() {
    if (Armor() == 0) {
        string act1;
        printf("Enter activity you need: ");
        cin >> act1;
        transform(act1.begin(), act1.end(), act1.begin(), [](unsigned char c) { return tolower(c); });

        if (strncmp(act, "calculator", actlen)) {
            Calculator();
        } else if (strncmp(act, "timer", actlen)) {
            Timer();
        } else {
            cout << "Sorry, but we haven't " << act << "!" << endl;
        }
        printf("Thank's for using us!");
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Тут какой-тот баг (скорее всего в функции *PasswordArmor*), но но отображается только такая ошибка:
[image: баг в с++]

Comment: в коду или в году или в коде?..

Comment: Вот и нету бага!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема у вас в том, что вы вводите два слова, но читается-то одно -

```
string name;
printf("Enter your name: ");
cin >> name;
for (auto a : names) {
    if (name == a) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Так что у вас возвращается и в конечном счете и `main` возвращает 1... О чем и сообщается на экране.

---

Но вот поясните глубокий смысл вот этого:

```
    string act1;
    printf("Enter activity you need: ");
    cin >> act1;
    size_t actlen = sizeof(char) * act1.length();
    char *act = (char*) malloc(actlen);

    for (int i = 0; i < actlen; i++) {
        act[i] = act1[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < actlen; i++) {
        act[i] = tolower(act[i]);
    }
    cout << '\n';
    if (strncmp(act, "calculator", actlen)) {
        Calculator();
```

Если можно было просто и незатейливо:

```
    string act1;
    printf("Enter activity you need: ");
    cin >> act1;

    if (act1 == "calculator") ...
```

В крайнем случае, добавить

```
 transform(act1.begin(), act1.end(), act1.begin(),
    [](unsigned char c){ return tolower(c); });
```